# R dplyr mutate does not work with as.Date(NA) 'origin' must be supplied

Tags: r, date, if-statement, dplyr, na

So I have this very weird situation. With R and date Conversion with as.Date() function. The weirdest thing is that ifelse statement does not work as it supposed to work.

So situation:

I want to extract date from number but stuck on situations where NA occurs. 
If I apply as.Date(NA) I do not get any error. But weird things starts on dataFrames.

Here is example:

```
###### create temp data.frame
t1 <- data.frame(dateNum = c(6000,6001,NA))

##### First attempt: straight ############
t2 <- t1 %>% dplyr::mutate(
    dateConverted = as.Date(dateNum)
)

##### Second attempt: ifelse statement ############
t2 <- t1 %>% mutate(
    dateConverted = ifelse(is.na(dateNum),NA,as.Date(dateNum))
)

##### Third attempt: ifelse statement for number 6000 ############
t2 <- t1 %>% mutate(
    naValue = is.na(dateNum),
    dateFixed = ifelse(naValue,6000,dateNum),
    dateConverted = ifelse(naValue,NA,as.Date(dateFixed))
)
```

And here is output. With errors ***'origin' must be supplied***

```
> ###### create temp data.frame
> t1 <- data.frame(dateNum = c(6000,6001,NA))
> 
> ##### First attempt: straight ############
> t2 <- t1 %>% dplyr::mutate(
+     dateConverted = as.Date(dateNum)
+ ) Error in as.Date.numeric(c(6000, 6001, NA)) : 'origin' must be supplied
> 
> ##### Second attempt: ifelse statement ############
> t2 <- t1 %>% mutate(
+     dateConverted = ifelse(is.na(dateNum),NA,as.Date(dateNum))
+ ) Error in as.Date.numeric(c(6000, 6001, NA)) : 'origin' must be supplied
> 
> ##### Third attempt: ifelse statement for number 6000 ############
> t2 <- t1 %>% mutate(
+     naValue = is.na(dateNum),
+     dateFixed = ifelse(naValue,6000,dateNum),
+     dateConverted = ifelse(naValue,NA,as.Date(dateFixed))
+ ) Error in as.Date.numeric(c(6000, 6001, 6000)) : 'origin' must be supplied
>
```

Comment: as @Kara Woo said supply an origin and your code will work, eg:  `t1 %>% mutate(dateNum = as.Date(dateNum, origin="2000-12-31"))`

Comment: Yes You are correct. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is not with the `NA` or with dplyr, it's with your numeric data. From `?as.Date`:

> 'as.Date' will accept numeric data (the number of days since an
>        epoch), but *only* if 'origin' is supplied.

You're passing the function numeric values (6000 and 6001), but no information about what those represent. `as.Date()` will treat these values as the number of days since an origin, but you have not provided an origin for it to calculate based on.